# ESP8266 code not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arduino, localhost, iot, esp8266

This is ESP8266 code to turn ON/OFF an LED. I'm using the Arduino IDE built-in example code. The LED is working properly but I want to send HTTP requests to my locally-hosted web site (which send emails) but it's not working.

1. Connected with my local Wifi
2. Assigned a static IP
3. When I hit 192.168.1.101/gpio/1(Led ON)
4. When I hit 192.168.1.101/gpio/0(Led OFF) It's working but unable to hit my web site.
5. When I hit 192.168.1.101/gpio/1 then it should hit my locally-hosted URL (192.168.1.100/home/ardchk)

Kindly help me to sort out this issue.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "SMART";
const char* password = "123456789";
const char* host = "192.168.1.100"; // Your domain
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 101); // where xx is the desired IP Address
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1); // set gateway to match your network
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  // prepare GPIO3
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(3, 0);
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.config(ip,gateway,subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()) {
    delay(1);
  }
  // Read the first line of the request
  String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(req);
  // Match the request
  int val;
  if (req.indexOf("/gpio/0") != -1) {
    val = 0;
    if (client.connect(host, 80)) {
      //starts client connection, checks for connection
      Serial.println("connected to website/server");
      client.println("GET /home/ardchk HTTP/1.1"); //Send data
      client.println("Host: 192.168.1.100");
      Serial.println("Email Sended");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      //close 1.1 persistent connection
      client.println(); //end of get request
    }
  } else if (req.indexOf("/gpio/1") != -1) {
    val = 1;
  } else {
    Serial.println("invalid request");
    client.stop();
    return;
  }
  // Set GPIO2 according to the request
  digitalWrite(3, val);
  client.flush();
  // Prepare the response
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\nGPIO is now ";
  s += (val)?"high":"low";
  s += "</html>\n";
  // Send the response to the client
  client.print(s);
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  // The client will actually be disconnected
  // when the function returns and 'client' object is destroyed
}
```

Comment: Please explain what happens when you try to hit url. "Not working" is not clear

Comment: You need to learn to spell (capitalizing letters randomly doesn't count as proper spelling), and to indent your code properly. Fortunately the Arduino IDE does this for you: press ctrl-T...

Comment: The code block:                                                                                                 if (client.connect(host, 80))                                                      
  {This Code is Not Running Because Not Connect With Host}                          even Website is hosted on same network

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question/comment, I am assuming that `client.connect(host, 80)` is returning false.

I believe you are unable to connect to your `host` because your are trying to connect twice with the same `client`.

Your code looks like this:

```
// returns an already connected client, if available
WiFiClient client = server.available()

//...

if (client.connect(host, 80)) {/*...*/}
```

You see, you are using the *already connected* client to attempt to *connect* to your host. Instead, try creating a separate `WiFiClient` for that job:

```
WiFiClient requesting_client = server.available();
//...
if (req.indexOf("/gpio/0") != -1) {
  val = 0;
  // create a fresh, new client
  WiFiClient emailing_client;
  if (emailing_client.connect(host, 80)) {
    // ...
    // don't forget that you need to close this client as well!
    emailing_client.stop();
  }
```

Hope this helps!